# How to passed parament the imageView in class adapter, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

class AdapterPostagem ( val car: MutableList): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPostagem.CarViewHolder>(){

```
inner class CarViewHolder ( itemView: View ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder( itemView ) {
    fun bind(car: Car) {
        with(car) {
            itemView.txtNameCar.text = nameCar
            itemView.txtBrandCar.text = brandCar
            //This line, in AndroidStudio not accept this formated
            itemView.imgCar.imageView = imgCar
            itemView.txtDescri.text = descCar
            itemView.txtPrice.text = priceCar
            itemView.txtYearsCar.text = yearCar
        }
    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CarViewHolder {
    val view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_postagem, parent, false)
    return CarViewHolder( view )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = car.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CarViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind( car[position])
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image string, you need to use an image processing library for displaying your images in an image view. Some of the popular libraries are [Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/).
A simple way to display your image, if you are using let's say Glide, would be

```
Glide.with(context).load(imgCar).into(itemView.imgCar)
```